CoreData managed object not properly deleted in child context
I have two contexts, MAIN and VIEW. I construct an object in MAIN and it appears in VIEW (which I use to display it in the UI). Then I delete the object in MAIN. Because the UI holds a reference to the object in VIEW, VIEW records it as a pending delete (Problem 1). I don't understand why it does this nor can I find this behaviour documented. Docs for deletedObjects say "objects that will be removed from their persistent store during the next save". This has already happened!
(Problem 2) Then I rollback the VIEW context, and the object is resurrected. awakeFromInsert is called again. While the object (correctly) does not appear in a freshly executed fetch request, it does appear in the @FetchRequest of the SwiftUI View which is now displaying stale data. How can I get SwiftUI to execute the fetch request again (I know I can force regeneration of the UI, but would like to avoid this).
This is a self-contained demonstration of the problem that can be run in a Playground. Press Create, then Delete (note console output), then Rollback (note console output, and that element count changes from 0 to 1 in the UI)
import CoreData
import SwiftUI

@objc(TestEntity)
class TestEntity : NSManagedObject, Identifiable{
    @NSManaged var id : UUID?
    override func awakeFromInsert() {
        print("Awake from insert")
        if id == nil {
            // Avoid resetting ID when we resurrect the phantom delete
            self.id = UUID()
        }
        super.awakeFromInsert()
    }
    
    
    class func add(in context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> UUID {
        let id = UUID()
        context.performAndWait {
            let mo = TestEntity(context: context)
            mo.id = id
        }
        return id
    }
    
    class func fetch(in context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> [TestEntity] {
        let fr = TestEntity.fetchRequest()
        return try! context.fetch(fr) as! [TestEntity]
    }
}

class CoreDataStack {
    // Main is attached to the store
    var main : NSManagedObjectContext!
    
    // View is a child context of main and used to display the UI
    var view : NSManagedObjectContext!
    
    // Set up a simple entity with an ID attribute
    func getEntities() -> [NSEntityDescription] {
        let testEntity = NSEntityDescription()
        testEntity.managedObjectClassName = "TestEntity"
        testEntity.name = "TestEntity"
        let idAttribute = NSAttributeDescription()
        idAttribute.name = "id"
        idAttribute.type = .uuid
        testEntity.properties.append(idAttribute)
        return [testEntity]
    }
    
    init() {
        let model = NSManagedObjectModel()
        model.entities = getEntities()
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "TestModel", managedObjectModel: model)
        let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription()
        description.type = NSInMemoryStoreType
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]
        container.loadPersistentStores { desc, error in
            if error != nil {
                fatalError("Failed to set up coredata")
            }
        }
        main = container.viewContext
        view = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        view.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        view.parent = main

    }
    
    func create() {
        let entityId = TestEntity.add(in: main)
        main.performAndWait {
            try! main.save()
        }
    }
    
    func delete() {
        main.performAndWait {
            if let mo = TestEntity.fetch(in: main).first {
                main.delete(mo)
                try! main.save()
            }
        }
        self.view.perform {
            // We only find that we have a pending delete here if we hold a reference to the object, e.g. in the UI via @FetchRequest
            if(self.view.deletedObjects.count != 0) {
                print("!!! view has a pending delete, even though main has saved the delete !!!")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func rollback() {
        self.view.perform {
            self.view.rollback()
            // PROBLEM We now have a resurrected object. Note that awakeFromInsert
            // was called again.
        }
    }
}

import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

let stack = CoreDataStack()

struct ContentView: View {
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) private var entities: FetchedResults<TestEntity>


    @State var renderID = UUID()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(entities.count) elements")
            Button("Create") {
                stack.create()
            }
            Button("Delete") {
                stack.delete()
            }
            Button("Rollback") {
                stack.rollback()
                // PROBLEM After rollback we get the element displaying in
                // the UI again, even though it isn't present in a freshly
                // executed fetch request.
                // The @FetchRequest is picking up the resurrected TestEntity in view
                // But not actually issuing a fetch.
                self.renderID = UUID()
                entities.nsPredicate
            }
        }.id(renderID)
    }
}

let view = ContentView()
    .environment(\.managedObjectContext, stack.view)

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(view)


I raised a technical support request with Apple. The responding developer agreed it was strange and asked me to file a feedback request. I did that, and now it looks like I'm in the blackhole that is the Apple bug reporting system.
